# Tag regular JavaScript file as Vue Component with WebStorm

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using Vue.js without a build step (plain ES modules), so I don't have any *.vue files available, just bare *.js files.

How do I tell WebStorm that those objects are Vue components and enable syntax support & highlighting?

Example:

```
// SomeComponent.js
export default {
  name: 'SomeComponent',
  template: `<div>Hello from SomeComponent</div>`
}
```

Comment: Vue.js components defined in separate `.js` files (linked to HTML pages via `<script>` tags) are supported since v. 2019.3, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32274. What does your app setup look like? do you have Vue.js installed with npm, or linked to HTML via CDN link, or?

Comment: Thank you! Vue is loaded via cdn (unpkg). I'll have a look at that link!

Comment: CDN support has been added in 2020.1 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40474)